# Can you explain more specifically about there is no simple group of size 96

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For the solution,I know that the number of Sylow-$2$ subgroups, $n_2=3$, and we can find a subgroup of order $32$,then $G$ can act on the left cosets of $H=P_2$, then it gives a map from $G$ to $S_3$, and what's the next? I have read some articles including a article here named" No simple group of $96$" but I still don't understand how to use this way to finish the proof.

Comment: It is important to know that the map from $G$ to $S_{3}$ is a group homomorphism, not just any old map ( the answer of Mathmo123 explains why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a non-trivial homorphism $\theta: G \to S_3$. But $|S_3| = 6 < 96$. So $\theta$ cannot be injective. In particular, $K = \ker \theta$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.

($\theta$ is non-trivial, since conjugation is transitive on the Sylow $2$-subgroups, so $K \ne G$ )

---

In general:

> If $G$ has a subgroup of index $k$ (i.e. $H<G$ and $\frac{|G|}{|H|} =k$) then if $|G|>k!$, then $G$ is not simple

*Proof:* in the same way as above, we can act on the left cosets of $H$ to get a non-trivial, non-injective homomorphism $G \to S_k$.

Comment: It's also important to note that this action isn't trivial which also follows from Sylow's theorems since conjugation is a transitive action on the 2-sylow subgroups.

Comment: But I have one more question,why we need to consider whether the θ is non-trivial?

Comment: Even if K=G, what will happen?

Comment: If $K=G$ then $G$ can still be simple. We need $K$ to be a non-trivial normal subgroup. That $\theta$ is non trivial tells us $K\ne G$. That it is non-injective tells us that $K \ne \{e\}$